# Install Java 16 on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, java-16

I have tried multiple releases from [here](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk16-binaries/releases/tag/jdk16u-2021-05-08-12-45) using :

```
sudo -i 
cd /usr/lib/jvm
wget [release link here]
tar xzf [file name here]
export PATH=$PWD/[dir here]/bin:$PATH
java -version
```

But after `java -version` I always get:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/[dir here]/bin/java: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Which means I have chosen the wrong release/architecture. Is there a release that works with Raspberry Pi's or is there another way to install Java 16?

Comment: Which one did you try? The Raspberry may need some of the "_arm_" based releases.

Comment: Tried some ARM based ones and eventually got it to work thanks to this thread: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/nvp14a/install_java_16_on_raspberry_pi_4/). Thanks for the help anyways :)

Comment: Please have a look on this [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4683/how-to-install-the-java-jdk-on-raspberry-pi/4845) from RaspberryPi-SE

Comment: @gkhaos This question is for Java 16.

Comment: @resuther the answer is adaptable to any custom java installation

Comment: There is a raspberry pi forum here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Answering my own question.

`cd [minecraft directory here]`

`wget https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk16-binaries/releases/download/jdk16u-2021-05-08-12-45/OpenJDK16U-jdk_arm_linux_hotspot_2021-05-08-12-45.tar.gz`

`tar xzf OpenJDK16U-jdk_arm_linux_hotspot_2021-05-08-12-45.tar.gz`

`export PATH=$PWD/jdk-16.0.1+4/bin:$PATH`

`java -version`

You might have to do
`export PATH=$PWD/jdk-16.0.1+4/bin:$PATH`
after a reboot